# Sequelize won't include SELF JOIN

Tags: sql, postgresql, sequelize.js

I have the following sequelize model defined (using seqeulize-typescript):

```
@Table
export class Entity extends Model<Entity> {

    @Column
    name: string;

    @ForeignKey(() => Entity)
    @Column
    EntityId: number;

    @BelongsTo(() => Entity)
    Entity: Entity;

    @BeforeCount
    static enableRaw(options) {
      options.raw = true;
    }
}
```

As you can see it has a self-reference, but aside from that, there really isn't much going on, however, if I run the following query:

```
sequelize.models.Entity.findAll({
        where: {
            EntityId: hook.params.headers.entityid
        },
        include: [sequelize.models.Entity]
    }).then(val => {
        hook.result = val;
        return hook;
    })
```

Then I get the error:

> SequelizeDatabaseError: table name "Entity" specified more than once

This goes away if I remove `include: [sequelize.models.Entity]` from the query. Obviously sequeliuze is confused that I am doing a self JOIN and I want to get all child rows of `Entity` which belongTo the current row.

Comment: you need to specify `as` attribute in self relationship scenarios

Comment: @HemantKumar OK, I've changed the query to `include: [{ model: sequelize.models.Entity, as: 'Children' }]`, but now I get error `Entity is associated to Entity using an alias. You've included an alias (Children), but it does not match the alias defined in your association.`?